# Gyroscope and Accelerometer movements in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, gyroscope

I need to create actions base to iPhone movements, it can be only in 4 directions: left, right, top, down.

I see Gyroscope have XYZ but how can I transform it to my directions? May I use Accelerometer?

Comment: X is left and right, Y is up and down. What's the problem?

Comment: Have you written any code yet? - It might be worth doing some research before asking a question on Stack, you could start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/).

Comment: sorry, gyroscope have not XYZ, it have roll, pitch, yaw